# Strophe.js in angular 4 application

Tags: angular, typescript, xmpp, strophe.js

I want to use Strophe.js library in an angular 4 application to connect to XMPP server. I have connected to server successfully. But I am not able to send presence so user is not showing online.

Can anyone please tell how to use $pres, receivemessage callback etc in typescript?

I used this "npm install strophe.js" command to install strophe & 
import { Strophe } from 'strophe.js';
in my .ts file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Strophe.js` has a type definitions for `TypeScript` which you can install it via

```
npm install --save @types/strophe
```

then you can import the type via

```
import {Strophe} from 'strophe';
```

after that you have full access of its functionality.

**Update**

Another solution would be declaring a variable like this:

```
declare let strophe: any;
```

Comment: I am getting this error after installing @types/strophe.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'strophe' in '/Lab/src/app'
resolve 'strophe' in '/Lab/src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Lab/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Lab/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)

Comment: @AditiPurohit, I have altered the `index.d.ts` and it worked, but I think it wouldn't be appropriated for you. I recommend you using second method (declare let strophe: any).